# StreamSocket connection from HoloLens does not work properly

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, async-await, hololens

I'm working on a HoloLens app which works as a client in a client-server connection to a local server written in Java (you can assume the server is working properly).

HoloLens should open a StreamSocket and connect to the server, but for some reasons the code remains stuck in the process of connection.

The code is the following:

```
void Start ()
    {
        text = GameObject.Find("DEBUG_TEXT").GetComponent<Text>();
        Invoke("Connect", 7f);      
    }



 public void Connect()
    {

#if !UNITY_EDITOR
        Task.Run(async () => {
            try
            {
                socket = new StreamSocket();
                await socket.ConnectAsync(new HostName(ip), port); //STOP HERE
                writer = new StreamWriter(socket.OutputStream.AsStreamForWrite());
                reader = new StreamReader(socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead());

                await Send("Hi");
                await Receive();

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                text.text = e.Message;
            }
        });
#endif
    }
```

Basically, the code stops at the ConnectionAsync and never goes on. On the server side, the server notifies me with *"new client connected!"*, so i suppose HoloLens effectively connects, but something happens after.

Any idea of what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, and solved it with the method mentioned [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3da6ac41-f2f6-4f8e-9f3b-eef36728a9d3/streamsocketconnectasync-never-completes-in-c-apps-was-winrt-component-behaves-differently-in?forum=winappswithcsharp).

In short, you should never do anything like Task.Wait() or Task.Result on the main thread.

In my situation, I used Task.Result and stuck right at the connect operation.
After removing it, the program works fine.

Here's the bad code:

```cs
private async Task<string> _SocketSend(string request)
{
    using(StreamSocket streamSocket = new StreamSocket())
    {
        await streamSocket.ConnectAsync(new HostName(this.socketHost), this.port);
        
        // other code
        ...
    }
    
}

public string SocketSend(string request)
{
    return _SocketSend(request).Result;
}
```